# What is the "Boundary Method" when solving for a function's domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For context, this is in a pre-calculus class.

I'm doing a work packet and one of the questions asked is:
"Find the domain of $$f(x)=\sqrt{40+7x-3x^2}$$
using the boundary method."

Now, I've looked in all of the notes our teacher provided and also the ones I've taken myself in class, and he has not mentioned a "boundary method" once. I'm scared if I solve the domain another way I'll get points taken off, so does anyone know what he means by this and how to do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wild guess.  Figure out where $40+7x-3x^2=0$, put those points on a number line.  This breaks the line into at most 3 regions.  Now figure out on those regions where this is nonnegative.

Comment: But, of course, the best way to get an answer to this is to ask your actual instructor.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding Domain via Boundary Method**

$$f(x)=\sqrt{40+7x-3x^2}$$
We know that the domain of the square root function is
$$\left\{x\in\mathbb R:x\ge 0\right\}$$
Which yields the following restriction
$$40+7x-3x^2\ge 0$$
After factoring via [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division?wprov=sfla1), we have
$$40+7x-3x^2=-(x-5)(3x+8)$$
Now we can use the boundary method. Set this expression to zero to identify critical points
$$-(x-5)(3x+8)=0$$
Solving for $x$ yields the following critical points
$$x=-\frac83\quad\text{and}\quad x=5$$
Using the critical points, we can split the x-axis into the following intervals:
$$\left(-\infty, -\frac83\right)\text{, }\left(-\frac83, 5\right)\text{ and }\left(5, \infty\right)$$
Now let's test each interval
$$-(-5-5)(3(-5)+8)=-70\not\ge 0$$
$$-(0-5)(3(0)+8)=40\ge 0$$
$$-(10-5)(3(10)+8)=-190\not\ge 0$$
We can now see that $\left(-\frac83, 5\right)$ is the only interval that respects our restriction. Also note that the critical points also respect our restriction. Therefore
$$\mathrm{dom} f=\left\{x\in\mathbb R:-\frac83\le x\le 5\right\}$$
Or in interval notation
$$\mathrm{dom} f=\left[-\frac83, 5\right]$$